# Ruby on Rails app connected to the wrong Postgres Database in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Hello I just ran heroku run rails c and heroku ran it on  ⬢ immense-spire-28000 which is my staging database not infinite-38185. Any ideas how my production application got connected to my staging database and how I can switch it back?

Comment: Check your database.yml in config folder ?

Comment: what happens when you run " heroku run rails -c --remote production " ?  Are the env variables set correctly, have you checked in dashboard or command line?

Comment: this is what I get: